# Proof strategy for $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^n}{3^{n+1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

In order to take the limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^n}{3^{n+1}}$$

I did:

$$3^{n+1}>n2^n\implies \frac{1}{3^{n+1}}<\frac{1}{n2^n}\implies\\\frac{2^n}{3^{n+1}}<\frac{2^n}{n2^n}\implies \frac{2^n}{3^{n+1}}<\frac{1}{n}\implies\\ 0 <\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n}{3^{n+1}}<\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n} = 0$$ therefore by the squeeze theorem:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n}{3^{n+1}} = 0$$

Is my reasoning right? I only conjectured that $3^{n+1}>n2^n$ but I think there may be another way to prove it without induction. Any ideas?

Comment: Your reasoning is right as well as your conjecture. For showing it I would go with induction too..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write

$$\frac{2^n}{3^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{3}\cdot \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$$

and note $(2/3)^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ as $|2/3| < 1$ (recall, $x^n \to 0$ if $|x| < 1$).

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{2^n}{3^{n+1}}=\frac13 \left(\frac23\right)^n?$

Comment: @mfl yes, thanks for the comment.

Comment: $+1.$ The simplest answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

Let $0<k<1$ and set $1+x=1/k$. Then we have Bernoulli's inequality
$$
(1+x)^n\ge 1+nx \quad\text{(for integer $n\ge0$ and real $x\ge-1$)}
$$
or
$$
\frac{1}{k^n}\ge 1+n\left(\frac{1}{k}-1\right)=\frac{k+n(1-k)}{k}
$$
so
$$
k^n\le\frac{k}{k+n(1-k)}
$$
By the squeeze theorem, $\lim_{n\to\infty}k^n=0$.

If $|k|<1$, then $-|k|\le k\le |k|$ so, again by the squeeze theorem, $\lim_{n\to\infty}k^n=0$.

Bernoulli's inequality can be easily proved by induction.

<sub>Note that this is usually crucial for proving that the geometric series converges, so the argument $x^n\to 0$ for $|x|<1$ because the geometric series converges can be circular, depending on how the convergence of the series is established.</sub>

In your case, direct induction is just easier, but less general.

By the way, the same inequality shows that, for $k>1$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}k^n=\infty$.